# Litespeed doesn't optimize my all pictures

Tags: litespeed

google pagespeed gives "need optimization for news" for my website:
https://cutt.ly/DmoA3UU

I can't click bulk button more.Why, how can I solve it?

here is the panel

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did not see such a suggestion for your site from the google page speed. The screenshot you provided shows there's no more image left that needs to be optimized.
You can verify if images are being optimized from the Media>library, and show them in list mode.
I'd recommend the following things for your site optimization.

1. HTTP/3 is not working may be due to the firewall

   - Check Tool: https://http3check.net/?host=https%3A%2F%2Fbclinico.helvatica.com%2F
   - Follow https://docs.litespeedtech.com/cp/cpanel/quic-http3/#open-udp-port-443-at-the-firewall to fix the firewall issue.
2. Optimize image in WebP version and turn on the WebP replacement

   - https://docs.litespeedtech.com/lscache/lscwp/imageopt/#create-webp-versions
3. If no conflict, try to combine the JS files to reduce the page requests
4. Your node is located in Turkey. If most of your visitors come from the AU region, I'd recommend you to have CDN integrated to reduce the network latency. E.g.

   - https://quic.cloud/
   - https://www.cloudflare.com/